# NamedQuery and no entity mapping

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to achieve the following. I have a query and I would like to run it and return rows in a REST call.
I do not want to map the query to a physical table, how would I achieve this?
I use Spring Boot 1.5.2.

Comment: map the query to a physical table ??.

Comment: No, this has to be not mapped query as it is a result of joining couple of tables, I could create a view, but wanted to explore this opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

After some try and fixes, I got the following solution.
Create a POJO class, no @Entity annotation. You want to add packageScan instructions if it is not found.

```
public class ActivityReport1 {
    @Column
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    //Only getters

    public ActivityReport1(BigInteger id,
                           String title){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
}
```

In a class which is annotated with @Entity create the resultset mapping

```
@SqlResultSetMappings({
        @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "ActivityReport1Mapping",
                classes = {
                        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = ActivityReport1.class, columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "id"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "title")
                        })
                })
})
```

Add repository class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class IActivityReport1Repository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<ActivityReport1> getResults(String userLogin) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT " +
                        "t.request_id as id, t.request_title as title " +                      
                        "FROM some_table t ", "ActivityReport1Mapping");

        List<ActivityReport1> results = query.getResultList();
        return results;
    }
}
```

And finally, the service impl class.

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class ActivityReport1ServiceImpl implements IActivityReport1Service {
    private static final Logger _Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActivityReport1ServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private IActivityReport1Repository sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<ActivityReport1> runReport(String userLogin) {
        List<ActivityReport1> reportRows = sessionFactory.getResults(userLogin);
        return reportRows;
    }
}
```

If you face with "Could not locate appropriate constructor", this means that on Java side it could not map db types to java types.
In my case I had to change id from Long to BigInteger and Timestamp to java.util.date.